# Problems sorting data in django

Tags: python, django, sorting

I have three database models, Story, StoryVote and Comment.

```
class Story(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, blank=True, null=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    description = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=2000)
    exp_text = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    emailOnReply = models.NullBooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    comment_text = models.TextField()
    story = models.ForeignKey(Story, related_name="comments")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.comment_text

class StoryVote(models.Model):
    votes = models.IntegerField()
    story = models.ForeignKey(Story, related_name="votes")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.votes
```

I'm using:

```
all_stories = Story.objects.all()
```

to fetch details for all stories and im using this to fetch the comments in the template and count the number of comments that has been made to each story:

```
{% for story in all_stories %}
{{ story.title }}
{{ story.comments.all|length }}
{% endfor %}
```

and im using the following to get the votes:

```
{% for story in all_stories %}
{{ story.title }}
{{ story.votes }}
{% endfor %}
```

This works nicely but i want to get the output sorted.
I have read about a number of ways to sort the data but nothing works.
At first of course i was using the order_by() function but since im sorting on the "comments" field which is a related field to another model the order_by function work by sorting the data in table im in and it doesnt sort the data coming from the related table, so im getting all kinds of duplicates and no sorting.

After that i thought i would use the distinct function but that doesnt work when you use a related field to sort on, so thats out, too. Then i tried to use the dictsort() function in the template itself, so i fetched the necessary data like this:

```
commented = list()
i=0
for story in most_commented:
commented.append({'title': story.title, 'comments': story.comments.all().count()})
i = i + 1
```

and sending the list with dicts to the template and calling the dictsort() but nothing happened when calling that function:

```
commented|dictsort:"title"
```

So im lost about how to get this data sorted. Any help is appriciated.

Comment: There's [a whole section of the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/) on running aggregates (e.g. max number of comments for a set of stories) on data that you might find helpful.

Comment: Maybe you even just want something like `Story.objects.annotate(num_comments=Count('comment')).order_by('num_comments')`, but that could be way off base and I'm not where I can test it right now.

Comment: Hmm, yes, i read a little in that section but i found it a little difficult to understand, ill take another read at it

Comment: Seems like your comment Two-Bit Alchemist is the right one, i read through the aggregation documentation and now it makes a lot more sense... i try it out as soon as possible, although now that i understand the docs i dont need to look at an example anymore :) thanks for pointing me to the right direction and providing what seems to be the answer

Comment: You can always post whatever code you get working (or an example of it) and accept your own answer to help new users. Glad I got you on the right track regardless.

Comment: i got it worked and was going to post an answer, but then i ran into a wierd problem as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22733754/strange-behaviour-for-annotate-in-django

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure, the `{% regroup %}` template-tag will be your friend here.

Have a look at the chapters "regroup" and "Grouping on other properties" https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup

Comment: Hmm ok, ill have a look at it.. i need to sotrt the list and not regroup it though since i already have only one column extracted in the database query. I read about aggregation and annotation and it seems like thats exactly what i need to solve this. thanks anyway